# associating multiple time values with date in one column

Tags: excel, datetime

I have the a meter data with 30 min showing time in different columns and dates in rows like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdVSs.gif)

Is there any way I can associate the every time values with every date in rows like this like below.

I have been trying to use index match but I am unable to figure out what can work, tried different transpose and added the values as well, didn't work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgRLy.png)

Comment: Please include all relevant information within the body of the question so that it will remain valid, even if the link does not. Additionally, it's easier for visitors to help you if we don't need to click around for details. Also, we need to see your  Minimum Viable Code example (in text format for easy copy-paste).  Thank You, and good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your pictures, your data is on Sheet8. Therefore, type the following array formula into cell B2 on Sheet1 and drag down as far as necessary: (Line breaks added for readability)

```
= INDEX(Sheet8!$B$2:$G$8,
MATCH(DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2),DAY(A2)),Sheet8!$A$2:$A$8,0),
MATCH(ROUND(TIME(HOUR(A2),MINUTE(A2),SECOND(A2)),5),ROUND(Sheet8!$B$1:$G$1,5),0))
```

Note this is an array formula, meaning you must press Ctrl+Shift+Enter when entering it, instead of just Enter.

See below, I have the same formula but all in one sheet (i.e. references to Sheet8 are removed, and I change A2 to I2 in order to show all on one sheet, but otherwise the formula is the same.)

[image]

Comment: ive tried it but #N/A for all the cells i have expanded.

Comment: I just realized why: That is because your data on Sheet8 ranges from 1/1/16 until 7/1/16 and your data on Sheet1 is entirely on 8/28/2017. If the dates and times actually match up between sheets, then the formula will return the correct value. Otherwise, #N/A will result because the formula cannot find a date and time match from the table on Sheet8.

Comment: sorry for the bothering but the other time was just to show that the sample i required, i even tried with the same time but the index match is still showing N/A

Comment: I think I found what the problem is. The `TIME` function can cause a rounding error. If you force it to round to a certain number of digits, then it doesn't seem to be a problem. See my original post above - I made a modification to account for this. Also note this is an array formula. (You must press Ctrl+Shift+Enter after typing the formula.)

Comment: Thanks Peter for all the help, perhaps its the time, but Iam again having the same N/A. Iam trying to work around it.

Comment: I'm not sure why it isn't working. See my original post once more. I edited it to show that it is working in my spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks Peter its working for the sheet, i fixed the time format. Thanks alot so grateful

Comment: Glad it is working. I would appreciate if you marked my answer as correct by placing a checkmark next to it and up-voting it.

Comment: Thanks peter for all the help, ive marked the answer is correct and voted it as well